# Copy elision and move semantic in return value

Tags: c++, c++11

**Background.**

I used to write C++ code and now I've started again. I'm reading some books that cover c++11 (and greater) features. There are many sophisticated answers on stack overflow as well but I just need a simple one.

When dealing with pointers I used to follow the famous *rule of three* but now I see that there's the new **move semantic** so the rule has been renamed to *rule of five*. Reading online I've seen that C++ has evolved and now there's also the copy elision. I have a lot of new concepts in mind right now. Look at this:

```
struct Test {};

auto getNewTest() { return Test(); }
auto x = getNewTest();
```

In this case (assuming that the copy elision is enabled) the only copy that occurs should be when I assing a value to `x` (only 1 copy). Before instead there would have been 2 copies: 1 as return value and 1 to assing to x the value.

So far so good but with move semantics I can achieve the same (if I'm correct)! Suppose that Test has move operations properly assigned; I could call this:

```
auto getNewTest() { return Test(); }
auto x = std::move(getNewTest());
```

---

**Question**

I've understood that moving is good when I have to get rid of an old variable and, instead of copying it to a new one, I can move all its content in a new one.

It happens that I have a statement like `return SomeClass(1,2,3)` and I want to avoid too many copies. Does the **std::move()** do zero copies? Because the copy elision avoids 1 copy (the returned value) and does only 1 copy because of the copy constructor.

My guess is that with std::move() I steal the object created from the function so I have zero copies. Am I correct? This may be banal in general but it took quite a lot to me.

Comment: Your first example will do zero copies on any decent compiler.

Comment: `std::move` actually does nothing, it is only used to pass a value into overloaded function variant that takes an rvalue reference. Note that in C++17 those rules changed (and may change again with C++20) so in your first example no copy or move occur.

Comment: `std::move(getNewTest());` is pointless, the result is already an rvalue.

Comment: I'm using visual studio which should have a decent compiler so I won't worry about that.

Comment: Well, vc++ compiler has been notorious for ignoring standards, doing things their own way and ignoring performance issues. Things has been changing lately however vc++ has no support for C++11 mode. It is possible to compile only in some mixed C++14+ mode or C++17 mode.

Comment: @VTT I'd like to ask another thing. When you have a function that accepts complex data types (vectors, classes, structs...) do you usually create 2 overloads of that with move and non move? such as `int t(const std::vector<int>& a){}` and `int t(std::vector<int>&& a){}`

Comment: Only if that function is actually going to duplicate the content of container passed somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking things.  With your code as written,

```
auto x = getNewTest();
```

Actually constructs `x` in place, and that's about as efficient as you can get.

This behaviour is guaranteed in C++17, but in practise it's worked that way for a long time now.

More [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  I can't recommend cppreference too highly, although it is not authoritative.